# How dangerous is a tire with a cut in the sidewall (filled with nitrogen)?

Tags: tires, sidewall-damage, nitrogen

I have an Audi TT and my tires are filled with nitrogen. I also have a cut on the sidewall of my front passenger tire.

How dangerous is that?

Comment: The atmosphere is 70% Nitrogen anyway.... which is a very unreactive gas.

Comment: Nitrogen is reactive, definitely not a noble or inert gas - where do you get all the oxides of Nitrogen from?

Comment: If that nitrogen gets into the atmosphere.... well, nothing will happen. If you have a high speed blow out because you didn't want to spend money on a new tire, that could be a huge issue.

Answer (score 4):

Nitrogen is a gas but not likely to catch fire.
However, the cut needs to be checked, preferably by a professional, as soon as possible - as it could cause the tyre to fail, with disastrous consequences.